# Display multiple years of data by polygon through time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, modelbuilder, symbology

[image]

I am working in ArcMap 10.7, examining population change of 2 different species through a 30 year period. My attribute table has 100 counties of which I am trying to symbolize the population count values by year for each county of the 2 species. I don't know how to go about symbolizing the species by each year.

Can anyone help me tackle this?

You can see in the screenshot I have GrFxCnt (grey fox count) and RdFxCnt (red fox count) by year...this spans through 2016.

Comment: @Hornbydd attached an image of a portion of the attribute table. TIA

Comment: Exactly which data you want to symbolize? And do you want a time-series map or a single map showing the overall change rate?

Comment: Think about what message you're trying to convey with this data. Is in relative populations of the two species each year? Change in headcount over time for each species? Primary habitat range shifting geographically over time? Do all 30 individual time points matter, or could you summarize it with time points every 5-10 years? What message you are trying to communicate is likely to result in some very different maps/graphs, and no matter what you probably want to be considering a series of maps, potentially with other supporting tables/charts.

Comment: Could you use an animation or do you need hard copy?

Comment: @ycartwhelen the message I am hoping to convey is how the land use over time is impacting population of the 2 species. So a change in count overtime for each species is desirable, but I don't think it needs to be by each year. more likely over a period like 5-10 years. I am just not sure how to go about symbolize this most effectively. Any suggestions? TIA

Comment: @PadmanabhaChowdhury I am trying to symbolize the pop count per year. a time series map would be great. I am very new to GIS and any help is much appreciated. TIA

Comment: If you want to show how land use is impacting population you need to show how land use is changing too. If your focus is on one type of land use (i.e. amount developed, or non-forest) you could use a bivariate map (fox population vs % of XXX type of land use) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_map. Or you could have an underlaying land cover map with some kind of point symbol per county on top for each type of fox population. Either way, you want one map per time point. Also consider if it's important to know total fox population, or if one species being impacted more than the other.